# Unable to load bower components

Tags: javascript, bower

I have the following directory structure:
- server.js and bower_components/ in the same folder
- in the public folder, index.html

In my html file I am trying to load bower components but they fail. Why is this happening?

```
<script src='../bower_components/angular/angular.js'></script>
<script src='../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js'></script>
```

Comment: what is the error you getting? The path may be wrong

Comment: Loading failed with the source. The path must be currect

Comment: try putting `bower_components` inside `public` folder and remove `../` from `src` script property.